# Providing dependencies in Java application

Tags: java, jar, dependency-management

I'm developing container-like application on Java which can host another Java-based applications (like Google App Engine). Currently I'm using `Maven Assembly Plugin` to assemble the hosted applications into one super-JAR with all the dependencies, but it looks like a bad practise.

Is there some libraries or tools to provide the dependencies at a runtime? I mean, I want to make a JAR only for hosted component-specific classes, without any dependencies, and store the dependencies list inside this JAR (in `pom.xml` or somewhere else). Host application will read this manifest and load required libraries to runtime. Is there any ready solutions?

Comment: If you provided the class-path element in the Jars manifest, then the class loader will load then automatically

Comment: As in, you want something to actually download and install dependencies at run-time?

Comment: I want something like Maven but in runtime. @MadProgrammer - dependencies can be in remote repository

Comment: Have you considered OSGi?

Comment: I've heard about `Apache Felix` but never tried it in production. Is it easy-to-use solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may have trouble with a tool like this; Java can load things dynamically at run-time too.    This may work for you though: http://depfind.sourceforge.net ...

If you really need to get the size down, you may use the verbose flag in the java vm to see all the classes that are loaded.  You will have to execute all the code to get the classes as they are loaded only when used (and loaded only once).  Further, it is uncommon, but different classes may load depending on the platform.

Comment: I meant something like Maven but in runtime - all the dependencies will be listed, and my host will just read the list, download JARs, load them into the Runtime and then load component. The main question is the classes conflict, not size